# Algorithm Suggestion for periodic alerts

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, search-problem

I am making a webapp that alerts when product prices fall or rise above a number. Let's say a product costs 100 and the user wants to be alerted when it reaches 80, the prices change every hour or so and I need to trigger all the alerts. What is the best way for this to make this work.

What I have tried so far?

**Approach 1**
At the time of setting the alert, if the price was 100 and user wanted 80, I am classifying this as a "less" alert or if the price was 100 and user wanted 120, I classify this as a "great" alert
If the price reaches 75 at a later point in time, I have a "less" alert whose value is greater than 75 and therefore I trigger it

(type=less and current_price > alert_price) or (type=great and current_price < alert_price)

Is there a better algorithm to achieve the same task with perhaps lesser comparisons as this takes a lot of time to scan on the database with 1 million+ products (sequential scan)

Comment: Define "best" and "better".  How will you evaluate answers?  I don't understand why your proposed approach is slow.   Seems easy to only check alerts for the one product whose price has changed, rather than scanning the entire database.

Comment: @D.W. if I had 10000 alerts added in the database, is there some way to process only a subset of these alerts to trigger all the price rise alerts ,that would be better or best, default approach so far that I cooked up is to scan everything, take each alert, get the alert level, compare with the current price and decide to fire or not, does this always require a full scan

Comment: That doesn't answer my questions.